# rails - carrierwave nested form update actually creates repeats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two models: Portfolio and PortfolioPic.  PortfolioPic belongs_to Portfolio and Portfolio has_many portfoliopics.  I have a nested form that works properly and creates portfoliopics that belongs_to portfolio.  However, when I try to update the form, rather than updating each image, it creates new images.  For example, If at first I create two images, A and B, and then I try to update A and B, the database will contain two different A's and two different b's.  I have had this problem with nested forms before, but usually adding :id to the nested_attributes field in strong parameters fixes this.  In this case, it is not fixing it.  Any ideas?  Here is my code:

Portfolio model:

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :portfolio_pics
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :portfolio_pics,  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

PortfolioPic Model:

```
class PortfolioPic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :portfolio
    mount_uploader :port_pic, PortfoliofileUploader
end
```

Uploader:

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'
class PortfoliofileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
    include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
    def store_dir
       "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    version :picture, :if => :is_image?  do
        process :resize_to_fill => [166,166]
    end

    def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf bmp doc docx)
    end

    process :set_content_type
    process :save_content_type_of_model

    def save_content_type_of_model
        model.content_type = file.content_type if file.content_type
    end

    def is_image?(new_file)
        new_file.content_type.start_with? 'image'
    end

end
```

Portfolios_controller:

```
def update
    @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
    if @portfolio.update_attributes(portfolio_params)
        flash[:notice] = 'Portfolio has been succesfully updated'
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
    end
end

private

def portfolio_params
    params.require(:portfolio).permit(portfolio_pics_attributes:[:_destroy, 
              :title, :port_pic, :content_type, :id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually ends up being part of routes.  My routes were setup so that the :id was actually referring to a portfolio_pic when it actually should have referred to :portfolio.  After fixing my routes, the update action worked correctly.